# An Idiom to describe the action of botching a job when it is almost complete

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests, idioms, idiom-requests

I am looking for an idiom/phrase which is used to describe the action of botching up a job when it is almost complete. A similar idiom in another foreign language is "to drown/wreck a boat when it is almost about to dock". It will be great to get some ideas.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think 2 of the answers from there are repeated here, but [Hellion's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/571323/an-idiom-to-describe-the-action-of-botching-a-job-when-it-is-almost-complete/571328#571328) is worth keeping it open  or at least bridge.

Comment: @Cascabel That answer is also there, but not a reference (which is hardly a problem in this case). I can't splice: you could flag a moderator.

Comment: Yes you are right, and I missed it..it was a one-liner with no reference. But doesn't that make this post better?

Answer (score 5):

You could be **snatching defeat from the jaws of victory**:

> (idiomatic) To suddenly lose a contest one seemed very likely to win, especially through mistakes or bad judgment.
> <sub>*from [yourdictionary.com](https://www.yourdictionary.com/snatch-defeat-from-the-jaws-of-victory)*</sub>

While the definition refers particularly to a contest, it is applicable broadly to any situation where a positive outcome seems assured.

Answer (score 2):

Would [Choking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choke_(sports)) do?

> In sports, choking is the failure of a person, or persons, to act or behave as anticipated or expected.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choke_(sports)) This can occur in a game or tournament that they are strongly favoured to win, or in an instance where they have a large lead that they squander in the late stages of the event. It can also refer to repeated failures in the same event, or simply infer an unexpected failure when the event is more important than usual.

Wikipedia

Comment: My source is linked.  Thew word Choking is linked to Wiki, whicjh is the source of the quote.

Comment: We prefer not to go off-page to determine the validity of the source...

Comment: Please review our Help Center's guidance on [How to reference material written by others](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Please also explain in your words why you think this is an answer to the question asked. Otherwise there is no original content here.

Comment: I don't get what you're complaining about. As far as I can see, I linked to the original page, and quoted only the relevant portion in accordance with the guidelines.