# Rebuttal to the solution of "An Idiom to describe the action of botching a job when it is almost complete"

Tags: phrases, expressions, idioms

I asked this question a few days back and found that my question has been closed. I am reposting it as I think there are some subtle differences between the idiom/phrase I am looking for and the solutions suggested. Any critique of my argument is most welcome.

---

Here is my original question: "I am looking for an idiom/phrase which is used to describe the action of botching up a job when it is almost complete. A similar idiom in another foreign language is "to drown/wreck a boat when it is almost about to dock". It will be great to get some ideas".

---

The solutions proposed are:
////////////////////
"To stick the landing": The original meaning of this idiom is to land firmly after an aerobatic move. Hence "landing" is an essential step without which the whole move will fail. So I will prefer to use it where I am asking someone to be very careful about the finishing steps. But in my question, even if we do not do anything the boat will dock. We use this idiom when we are asking someone not to do anything stupid which can jeopardize a nearly completed job.///////////
" They danced but forgot to take a bow": This also has the same issue. Taking a bow is an integral step of the dance. So again I will use it when I am asking someone not to be over complacent when a job is near completion. But I think none of these convey the meaning that tells "do not do anything stupid to mess up a job that is almost complete".

Comment: If you want feedback...it looks like a pattern of rejecting good answers like "They danced but forgot to take a bow" or "dropped the ball." Instead of rejecting them for not matching your vision, leave them unchecked. A trained dancer can tell you that a bow is not any part of the dance, but a separate thank you to the audience.

Comment: This seems to be moving the goalposts from the original. The original question was about an idiom describing the action of botching a job when it is almost complete. This revision is now asking for a warning to "not do anything stupid to mess up a job that is almost complete".

Comment: I am not rejecting any answers, rather trying to politely put forward a cogent argument on why I feel there are subtle differences. I am trying to critique not criticize the answers given.

Comment: As I recall the original question was about a job badly done but successfully completed. The goal posts are being moved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"To snatch defeat from the jaws of victory"** See [yourdictionary.com](https://www.yourdictionary.com/snatch-defeat-from-the-jaws-of-victory)

> (idiomatic) To suddenly lose a contest one seemed very likely to win, especially through mistakes or bad judgment.
>
> Origin of snatch-defeat-from-the-jaws-of-victory
>
> An ironic reversal of "to snatch victory from the jaws of defeat" (From Wiktionary)

The saying is in extended use to cover not only a competition but also any enterprise.

Comment: This is the same as [Hellion's answer in the original post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/571323/an-idiom-to-describe-the-action-of-botching-a-job-when-it-is-almost-complete/571328#571328) from yesterday..

Comment: @Cascabel ... which I have not seen before. Great minds, etc.